# batch command to search and output the content between the first and last occurrence of the search key

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I have a log file and I have a keyword to search the log file. Now I have to extract all the contents from that log file between the first and the last occurrence of the search key. ie everything in between the first and last occurrence. the findstr command only lists out the lines that are having the search key and not the other contents in between. I need batch commands to do that.

eg.

```
log.txt
[mave123]sddasnsdaskdasddansnmdmsmdasdasda
[mave123]dfdfdf
fsffasf
safaaf
fasfssfdfdsfdsf
[mave123]dfsfsdfsdfssdfssfd
[mave124]rdfsdfsfsfsf
[mave124]dfdfsdfsfsdfs
```

now the "findstr mave123 log.txt" will return as below

```
[mave123]sddasnsdaskdasddansnmdmsmdasdasda
[mave123]dfdfdf
[mave123]dfsfsdfsdfssdfssfd
```

but I want all the contents between the fist and last occurrences of mave123. ie like this. Can you please help?

```
[mave123]sddasnsdaskdasddansnmdmsmdasdasda
[mave123]dfdfdf
fsffasf
safaaf
fasfssfdfdsfdsf
[mave123]dfsfsdfsdfssdfssfd
```

Comment: Please read the entire [tour page](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and learn how this site works!

Comment: Please note that https://stackoverflow.com is not a free script/code writing service. If you tell us what you have tried so far (include the scripts/code you are already using) and where you are stuck then we can try to help with specific problems. You should also read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "sourcedir=U:\sourcedir"
SET "destdir=U:\destdir"
SET "filename1=%sourcedir%\q35976147.txt"
SET "outfile=%destdir%\outfile.txt"
SET "target=%~1"
IF NOT DEFINED target GOTO :eof
SET "startline="
FOR /f "delims=:" %%a IN ('findstr /N /L /c:"%target%" "%filename1%" ') DO (
 IF NOT DEFINED startline SET /a startline=%%a
 SET /a endline=%%a
)
IF NOT DEFINED startline ECHO NOT found&GOTO :EOF

(
FOR /f "tokens=1*delims=:" %%a IN ('findstr /N /r "." "%filename1%" ') DO (
 IF %%a geq %startline% (
  IF %%a leq %endline% (ECHO %%b) ELSE (GOTO nextstep)
 )
)
)>"%outfile%"
:nextstep
GOTO :EOF
```

You would need to change the settings of `sourcedir` and `destdir` to suit your circumstances.

I used a file named `q35976147.txt` containing your data for my testing.

Produces the file defined as %outfile%

The first `for` prefixes each line number matching the target string with *linenumber*: then assigns the first line number found to `startline` and surprisingly the last to `endline`

The second `for` repeats the operation, this time outputting the lines in the range selected.

This will suppress any leading `:` on lines. I haven't tested blank lines.

---

Revision for "all matching files"

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "sourcedir=U:\sourcedir"
SET "destdir=U:\destdir"
SET "target=%~1"
IF NOT DEFINED target GOTO :eof
FOR %%j IN ("%sourcedir%\log_*.txt".) DO (
 ECHO %%j
 SET "startline="
 FOR /f "delims=:" %%a IN ('findstr /N /L /c:"%target%" "%%j" ') DO (
  IF NOT DEFINED startline SET /a startline=%%a
  SET /a endline=%%a
 )
 IF DEFINED startline (
  SETLOCAL enabledelayedexpansion
  (
  FOR /f "tokens=1*delims=:" %%a IN ('findstr /N /r "." "%%j" ') DO (
   IF %%a geq !startline! IF %%a leq !endline! (ECHO %%b)
  )
  ENDLOCAL 
  )>"%destdir%\%%~nj.out"
 ) ELSE (
  ECHO "%target%" NOT found IN %%j
 )
)
GOTO :EOF
```

Here, `%%j` receives the name of the file to be processed. The destination file is constructed from the destination directory name, the name part of the source file (`%%~nj`) and `.out` A `SETLOCAL/ENDLOCAL` bracket is established to allow the run-time values of `startline` and `endline` to be accessed.

- always best to state the complete problem as it often radically changes the approach.

Comment: thanks so much it really helped a lot. But can you also provide a solution where the source file is not one but a bunch of files. Like the files are named log_09212016.txt, log_09222016, log_09232016... and so on and I would like to search all of the files like log*.txt?